# Can I implement whitelisting and/or blacklisting in Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

We are considering implementing a whitelist or a blacklist in our maven repository in the production environment. Nexus3 supports this in their commercial offering. I can't find it in Artifactory. Is there a way to implement a blacklist or whitelist in Artifactory?

Comment: Could you tell me how you do it in Nexus 3? I did not find it.

Comment: I was using a trial version of their full lifecycle suite. It's not available in the community version, nor in the standard pro version afaik. Getting a trial version is a project in itself. I think I only received the trial license because the client I needed it for already has a license for other Sonatype products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have licensed Jfrog Xray, you can add issues there and use them to block an artifact in Artifactory from downloading.